# Страницы без перезагрузки на одном из сайтов

Tags: php, url, cms, продвижение

Случайно наткнулся на сайт https://likadress.ru и заметил, что переходы по ссылкам осуществляются без обновления страниц, однако при этом url меняется. Как это реализовано и не влияет ли такая технология на продвижение сайта в поисковых системах?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На указанном вами сайте используется связка **pushState** и **Ajax**. Для SEO не вредит

Готовая библиотека:
https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax

Comment: Насчет того, что Ajax не вредит SEO, это довольно спорное заявление.

Comment: freim, ну так если спорное - давайте спорить. Только прежде проверьте указанный в вопросе сайт на качество индексации в поисковиках. Нормально они его "схавали". Юзал данный способ и  уверяю, что используя библиотеку **pjax** позиции не пошатнутся

Comment: Никогда ранее не встречал данную технологию, спасибо за ответ. Однако вопрос о сео очень важен, так как если  pjax хоть немного ослабляет индексацию, то становиться ненужным инструментом. Буду изучать.

Comment: @Deus вопросы продвижения многих волнуют, но я думаю 16 тыс. звёзд у проекта на гитхабе о многом говорит